# How to autocompile data received via jQuery ajax using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have a page, all the real-time interactions with the server is done using jQuery ajax.

Now I'm porting the functionality step by step to AngularJS.

My problem is, that page content which is being grabbed and parsed using jQuery ajax, contains angular code which stops working after that until I refresh the page.

Is it possible to autocompile the content with angular during the parsing by jQuery?

Comment: Look at `$compile` service and the sample example given in the docs. It can help you http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

Comment: It's not a problem if you're doing compile inside the angular controller. But what if you have to do that outside of angular? Let's say in jQuery event handler function?

Comment: Can you not look at grabbing page content using ng-include it can do the same thing what jquery ajax call is doing

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there currently is no answer. I have had the same problem and have spent days searching EVERYWHERE for a solution to this seemingly very common problem. I have a site that uses ajax to load a template partial that contains some HTML that includes an angular directive. The directive doesn't work!